# TFS Integration Build With Obfuscation

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I'm using Team Foundation Service (previously known as tfspreview.com) and have created a Gated check-in integration build. The problem I'm having is now that I've gated the check-ins... I can't check anything in due to an obfuscation tool that has been merged into my project files.

It is looking for a file when building on the server which doesn't exist there because its on my machine... is there a way to pass in an MSBuild argument to say use obfuscation while processing a gated check-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check in that file to TFS so that the build server can find it.